# Cython & Python Project Test Driven Development and .pyx file structure advice

Tags: python, unit-testing, tdd, pycharm, cython

What is the best way to structure a `python/cython` project such that I can unit test code that resides in `.pyx` files? Is it possible to unit test this code in place or will refactoring allow me to achieve this in another way?

I am new to `cython` but have experience with Python TDD, mocking etc. I am also aware that the decision to cythonise some of the python code base *could* have been a premature optimisation decision. I have just joined a new team and therefore I am working on an existing code base. I am trying to get a feel for best practices.

Also in PyCharm, modules written in .pyx files are show as unresolved references in the editor - I have just read about `pyximport` but I am not sure if PyCharm is set up correctly for `cython` (I have the latest professional edition).

I am aware of the [cython user guide](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/) but I cannot find advice on testing. I am also aware of [pycharm's setup guide](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/cython-support.html) but this suggests that cython support is out of the box, which seems to contradict what I experience.

Comment: I resolved the PyCharm editor problem by adding .pyx to the recognised file types (I am not sure why this was missing).

Comment: Have you tried just adding your unit test code to the pyx file as if it was plain Python? Cython can handle the vast majority of plain Python code so there's a good chance it would just work (or only need tiny changes) and you wouldn't need to do anything special....

Comment: When I debug my tests, I cannot step into the pyx code. Is is possible to set up the debugger in PyCharm to achieve this?

Comment: I think that's expected. Have a look at http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/debugging.html (but it's clearly a different mechanism to normal Python debugging). I'm afraid I know nothing about PyCharm.

Comment: I believe this is an ongoing issue: it seems that debugging pyx files using the python debugger (pdb) is not possible yet, https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/apam-python-users/pdb$20cython/apam-python-users/6rsRwcCAms4/Cw1IY1nvldYJ

Comment: @rnoodle: How do you "add .pyx to the recognised file types"? Do you just add the extension to a plain text file?